# How to design user-independent error state on library initialization?

Tags: java, oop, kotlin

I'm making a minimal library that handles finding Steam and working with its (multiple) installations on the users disk.

First thing my library does is automatically find the steam folder on initialization (based on os), like this:

```
val steam = Steam()
```

However, what happens if the folder is not found? Should I throw an exception? 
Return null?

In my case throwing exceptions is weird on class init because there are no user supplied params to the constructor. Surrounding the class init with try blocks is awful too.

So I tried moving the folder location functionality to a separate function like this:

```
class SteamFind(filepath: String? = null) {
    var location: File? = filepath?.let { File(it) } // probably better off as a string

    val `cool property`: String by lazy {
        require(location != null)
        "cool"
    }

    fun locateSteam() {
        location = File(steamLocator.findSteamFolder())
    }

    fun `does cool stuff`() {
        require(location != null) { "Steam location must not be null" }
    }
}
```

Now I've moved the failing point from the constructor to a function, but that introduced problems of its own.
First of all, if I wanted variable properties in my code I'd have to slap nullable on all of them because they have to be initialized at some point, and lazy doesn't work on variable props. (i can probably solve it by extending lazy, but that's not desirable)
Second, I'd have to put require() everywhere, which is not desirable either.
Third, is throwing errors still a good idea? (i can append try to the function name of course). I actually somewhat fixed it by returning a discriminated union instead:

```
fun tryLocateSteam(): Either<String> {
        val result = attempt { steamLocator.findSteamFolder() }
        return when (result) {
            is Either.Success -> {
                location = File(result.value)
                result
            }
            is Either.Error -> result
        }
    }
```

meaning the user can choose to ignore the exception or check for it and specify the path manually

```
val s = SteamFind().apply { tryLocateSteam() }
// or
val s = SteamFind()
when (s.tryLocateSteam()) {
    is Either.Success -> //stuff
    is Either.Error -> //Manually assign the location property
}
```

So, here's the question: is there any better way of doing what I'm trying to do, presumably without the hassle of checking the nullability of 'location', making vars nullable, and being simple to use and understand for the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my case throwing exceptions is weird on class init because there are no user supplied params to the constructor.

Honestly, my answer would be: so what? Besides, you can add the user-provided location as a parameter (`null` means the library will attempt to locate it automatically):

```
class Steam(path: String? = null) {
    val location: File = if (path != null) {
        checkSteamIsThere(path) // throws if it isn't
        File(path)
    } else {
        locateSteam() // throws an exception if it can't locate Steam
    }
}
```

Then you can do, for example,

```
val steam = try { 
    Steam() 
} catch(e: SteamNotFoundException) { 
    val path = // ask user to enter path somehow 
    Steam(path)
}
```

Comment: Oh, I kinda forgot that you don't have to handle checked exceptions in kotlin. I made the Either sealed class just for that, lol

Comment: Note that Kotlin 1.3 has https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/index.html.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about it, but I'd also like to have java interop, so I went with a custom solution instead